# refreshSlides Exception: Action not allowed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I Have a working Google slides version 2020, I copied this to version 2021.
But now I get the error

```
Exception: Action not allowed
refreshSlides   @ Code.gs:9
```

The script is :

```
function refreshSlides(){
  var currentPresentation, i, linkedSlide, numSlides
  
  // loop through all slides and refresh them
    currentPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    numSlides = currentPresentation.getSlides().length;
    for (i = 0; i < numSlides; i++) {
      linkedSlide = currentPresentation.getSlides()[i]
      linkedSlide.refreshSlide();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);

    }
}
```

I tried to add authorization by adding (see below) to appsscript.json

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations"
  ],
```

But that didn't help.
What am I missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#refreshSlide()), `refreshSlide()` drops an error:

> If read-access to the source presentation is no longer available.

Make sure you have read-access to the active presentation and to every slide.

Comment: I'm working in the script editor of this presentation, so I assume that I have read-access....

Comment: do you have read access on every slide? @Jacobs

Comment: Is there an easy way to check that?
Im Editor for the presentation

Comment: @Jacobs Unfortunately I can't replicate the issue then.. ask the owner of the presentation to make you editor or remove unecessary protections.

Comment: Thank You Marios, I'm already Editor. but i will check if there are any protections.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, There was one slide that was a 'linked slide'
to the linked slide was no authorization.